# Plot for sankey diagram is empty

Tags: python, spyder, sankey-diagram

[Empty plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MzJS.png)

I'm new to python/spyder, and I'm trying to make a sankey diagram, but no data is included in the plot, it's just empty. I found out that I need to convert from dataframe to lists, but this hasn't helped, and the plot is still empty. I kept it very simple, and pretty much copied it straight from a guide from plotly, and just imported my own data.
Here is my code, where I just removed the filepath.
Can anyone tell my what my mistake is?
edit to add image of xlsx file : [xlsx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z76XE.png)
edit 2 image of new [Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuW9p.png)

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
# go.renderers.default = "browser"
df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\filepath\data.xlsx') 

labels=pd.DataFrame(df, columns= ['Label'])
label_list=labels.values.tolist()
sources=pd.DataFrame(df, columns= ['Source'])
source_list=sources.values.tolist()
targets=pd.DataFrame(df, columns= ['Target'])
target_list=targets.values.tolist()
values=pd.DataFrame(df, columns= ['Value'])
value_list=values.values.tolist()


fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    node = dict(
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 20,
      line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
      label = label_list,
      color = "blue"
    ),
    link = dict(
      source = source_list, 
      target = target_list,
      value = value_list
  ))])

fig.update_layout(title_text="Basic Sankey Diagram", font_size=10)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Please share your xls file screenshot

Comment: Hi I just added the image for the xls file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the snippet with random data.
[image: sankey]

When you are reading from excel, it gives you `dataframe` only. You dont need to store it again to `dataframe`.

Neither you need to convert it to `list`. You can pass dataframe column directly to `label,source,value and target`

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel (r'data.xlsx')
print(df)
"""
  Label  Source  Target  Value
0    A1       0       2      8
1    A2       1       3      4
2    B1       0       3      2
3    B2       2       4      8
4    C1       3       4      4
5    C2       3       5      2
"""
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    node = dict(
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 20,
      line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
      label = df['Label'],
      color = "blue"
    ),
    link = dict(
      source = df['Source'],
      target = df['Target'],
      value = df['Value']
  ))])

fig.update_layout(title_text="Basic Sankey Diagram", font_size=10)
fig.show()
```

**Tips**

Your `labels_list, source_list, target_list, value_list` is not a `list`. It is a `nested list`.

If you want to store your `dataframe` columns to a list then you can do like this,

```
labels_list=df['Label'].tolist()
source_list=df['Source'].tolist()
target_list=df['Target'].tolist()
value_list=df['Value'].tolist()
```

For more details you can refer
[Sankey Diagram Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/)

Comment: The values seem to be there now, but the labels are not. Can this be because not all labels are used yet? Or could there be another problem?

Comment: labels should also be there. Did you check the spelling correctly? from excel and in the code @TildeLyngsø

Comment: Label is spelled the same in both excel and the code. I just copied your code from your response, and it still doesn't show any labels. The issue might be something else then..

Comment: @Tilde Lyngso. Your `df['Label']` aint empty right?

Comment: No, it prints everything, so its there, it just doesn't show up on the plot..

Comment: Can you post screenshot of your plot? @TildeLyngsø

Comment: @TildeLyngsø I feel Your excel sheet `value` column is wrong. Why are you using `comma`? I dont get that values. Should it be decimal?

Comment: Right, I forgot to change that, in my country comma is used for decimal.

Comment: @TildeLyngsø Great . If you find my answer helpful you can accept it as answer

Comment: Is your data actually relevant to sankey plot? @TildeLyngsø Or is it some random data you generated?

Comment: It is relevant, it's for an overview of produced/imported and used/exported energy..

Comment: I will suggest you to read about sankey diagram via wikipedia and the link I attached in ansert. As each data should be interlinked, to display a flow among several fields and you are having negative data in `value` column. Please try to understand abt the structure of Sankey. I feel your data is not appropriate for sankey

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into it